# BroadcastReceiver not being called when package is removed or updates

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm registering a BroadcastReceiver statically and having it recognize when a package is added, removed, or replaced, but the onReceive isn't firing. Here's my manifest, where I have it registered:

```
<receiver android:name="com.generic.package.UpdateReceiver" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Then the full code of my receiver is this:

```
package com.generic.package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    Log.e("TEST","WENT INTO ONRECEIVE");
    }
  }
```

At first I thought it was because I was testing it on an S5 and I didn't have MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED, so I added that and tested on an older version but it's still not calling. In the Logcat I can see this receivers in the list of receivers. The only thing I can come up with is that I'm building and installing using Maven - is there something special I have to do with that? I also tried adding various tags to the receiver in the Manifest, like android:enabled="true" and android:exported="true", as well as adding priority to the intent-filter and none of them worked.

Comment: Remove the `<data>` element and see if that helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have changed anything. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that it was a Maven issue - when I transferred the APK to my phone and installed it that way, everything fired like normal. Lesson learned: even if it says it's an "install" through Maven, it doesn't fire any of those receivers!